# Explode an Array that has a new line in it in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that is separated by "|". What I wanna do is separate by this identifier.

The array is as follows:-

```
myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
myid3|My Title|Third row description
```

What I did was that I just used `explode` on it to get my desired results.

```
$required_cells = explode('|', $bulk_array);
```

But the problem is (as shown below) that only my first array is properly exploded and the next first cell of the next array is mixed due to the "new line".

Is it possible that I can get the upper array in consecutive array cells?

```
Array
(
    [0] => myid1
    [1] => My Title 
    [2] => Detailed Description
myid2
    [3] => My Title 
    [4] => Second Row Description
myid3
    [5] => My Title 
    [6] => Second Row Description
)
```

Comment: `explode` operates on strings. You don't have an array, you have a string. Why are all three records together inside a single string?

Comment: Do you want to explode on `|` AND newline? Or keep only the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode on newlines, aka `"\n"` first, then loop through that array and explode on pipes, aka `'|'`

```
$bulk_array = "myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
myid3|My Title|Third row description";

$lines = explode("\n", $bulk_array);

foreach ($lines as $key => $line)
{
    $lines[$key] = explode('|', $line);
}
```

Then `print_r($lines);` will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => myid1
            [1] => My Title
            [2] => Detailed Description
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => myid2
            [1] => My Title
            [2] => Second Row Description
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => myid3
            [1] => My Title
            [2] => Third row description
        )
```

)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) to explode on `|` and EOL:

```
$parts = preg_split('#(\||\r\n|\r|\n)#', $string); // EOL is actually 3 different types
```

Which makes 1 array with 9 elements.

Or first explode on EOL and then on `|`:

```
$lines = preg_split('#(\r\n|\r|\n)#', $string);
$lines = array_map(function($line) {
  return explode('|', trim($line));
});
```

Which makes 3 arrays with 3 elements each.

Comment: +1, but `preg_split` is really not needed. Just `explode(\n)` will work fine.

Comment: If you don't care about trailing `\r`, yes, and if the EOL isn't `\r` only.

Comment: Your `trim()` call handles `\r`'s on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_map`:

```
$str = "myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
  myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
  myid3|My Title|Third row description";

$newLine = (explode("\n", $str));
$temp = array();
$result = array_map(function($someStr) use(&$temp) { 
  $exploded = explode("|", $someStr); 
  foreach($exploded as $value) $temp[] = $value;
}, $newLine); 

print_r($temp);
```

[Sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c59e97f617625134bc6882fe3192ae8843768493), if you don't need it flatten you can drop the foreach part:

```
$str = "myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
  myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
  myid3|My Title|Third row description";

$newLine = (explode("\n", $str));
$result = array_map(function($someStr) { 
  return explode("|", $someStr); 
}, $newLine); 

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Wow, this was pretty perfect!

Comment: @Steve the output is a bit different from your showed result, but I figured that it doesn't makes sense to have a flat array in this case, you may want to have the different strings separate into different arrays.

Comment: `array_walk_recursive()` isn't necessary. There's no recursiveness.

Comment: @Rudie I wanted to keep the array flat and this was the best I could came up with, I made an edit with a new link to a sandbox, but yes indeed, `array_map` is more than sufficient.

Comment: This code works fine in PHP Version 5.4.10, but gives an error in PHP Version 5.2.14

Comment: @Steve `array_map` was added from PHP 5.4.