# Syntax issue of array_map while exploding in two different versions of PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I had an array that is separated by "|". What I wanted do was to separate it by this identifier.

The array is as follows:-

```
myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
myid3|My Title|Third row description
```

What I did was that I just used `explode` on it to get my desired results.

```
$required_cells = explode('|', $bulk_array);
```

But the problem was that only my first array was properly exploded and the next first cell of the next array was mixed due to the "new line". Hence I couldn't use explode only.

To get the upper array in consecutive array cells as follows, I used the code below:-
(with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516020/explode-an-array-that-has-a-new-line-in-it-in-php) thread)

```
Array
(
    [0] => myid1
    [1] => My Title 
    [2] => Detailed Description
myid2
    [3] => My Title 
    [4] => Second Row Description
myid3
    [5] => My Title 
    [6] => Second Row Description
)
```

The working code:-

```
$str = "myid1|My Title|Detailed Description
  myid2|My Title|Second Row Description
  myid3|My Title|Third row description";

$newLine = (explode("\n", $str));
$result = array_map(function($someStr) { 
  return explode("|", $someStr); 
}, $newLine); 

print_r($result);
```

This worked perfectly but then the problem occured. This code works fine in PHP Version 5.4.10, but gives the following error in PHP Version 5.2.14. My dev server is 5.4.10 and unfortunately my production server is 5.2.14 therefore I need to fix this issue. The error is as follows:-

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in page.php on line 310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode twice!

```
$result=array();
$lines=explode("\n", $str);
foreach ($lines as $line) 
  $result[]=explode('|', $line);
```

Or to stay with one dimension:

```
$result=array();
$lines=explode("\n", $str);
foreach ($lines as $line) 
  $result=array_merge($result,explode('|', $line));
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the array by exploding it once? So that it gives the same output of two dimensional array but with a different code?